# missing resource exception

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jsf

my application uses eclipse and run on Tomcat server.technology used is 'JSF'. while running my application i m getting exception like:

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key Content Management Exception

Please suggest what to do?

Answer (score 2):

May be because there are spaces in between, in your key. Try `ConentManagementException`, instead. I mean without spaces.

Answer (score 1):

- Check all your runtime dependencies
- Verify that they are all deployed and running
- Check that your `JAVA_PATH` is set correctly

If you want more information you are going to need to be more specific